# Can we Restrict pip install in jupyter cell/notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Can we restrict or disable pip install in jupyter.
I don't want to install any packages in my jupyter notebook.
any one have idea about it??

Comment: What if the user wrote code to download a .whl Python package file and extract in the correct place, i.e. doing the same thing as `pip install`? Wouldn't you need to block that too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know on what environment you are running but I guess you can change the permissions of the "user" that runs the notebook process so it won't have permissions to run `pip`

Comment: They could still `python -m pip`, or call the `pip` API programmatically.